# Javascript character counter, count carriage reurn as 2 characters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I have written a character counter in javascript ..like this

```
<textarea class="SmsText" id="txttemplate"  maxlength="160" />
<span id="charsCount">160</span></strong><span>character(s) left</span>
$(document).ready(function() {
        keypressed = false;
        $('#txttemplate').keypress(function (e) {
            keypressed = true;
        });

        $('#txttemplate').keyup(function () {
            counter($(this));
        });

        $('#txttemplate').keydown(function () {
            counter($(this));
        });

    });
function counter(obj) {
        var max = obj.attr('maxlength');
        var valLen = obj.val().length;
        obj.val(obj.val().substring(0, max));
        $('#charsCount').text(max - valLen);
    }
```

Now, my code considers "enter" key 13 as single character, but the maxlength attribute of textarea counts as 2.  WIth my Code, how can I make the count two chracters when "enter" or "carriage return is pressed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the key pressed event argument and increment your counter accordingly

```
$('#txttemplate').live("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //do increment here
    } 
}
```